# PHPMailer refuses to send email without attachment exists

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails with optional attachment file.
This is working fine when sending the email with attached file exist.
But the problem is PHPmailer refusing to send the email when attachment is empty, any fix?

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$msg = '';
$sender_name =  $_POST['sender_name'];
// Upload handled successfully
// Now create a message
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('info@*****.com', 'first last');
$mail->addAddress('info@*****.com');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
$mail->Body = "Contact form submission:\n" . "Name: $sender_name\n";

if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

        // Attach the uploaded file
        //$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');

        $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $ext = end((explode(".", $name)));
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'You Have Attachment.'.$ext);


    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}

if (!$mail->send()) {
    $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $msg .= "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

here is the html witch located under the PHP codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PHPMailer Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (empty($msg)) { ?>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="sender_name">
        <br>
        Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send File">
    </form>

<?php } else {
    echo $msg;
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your entire script where the actual sending is done depends on the fact if there is a file yes or no. This is handled by the if statements at the top of your script. I suggested an edit where the email will always be sent, and the file will only be added if there is a file yes or no. But since I'm on mobile I have no idea if the edit suggestion came through yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it, to be something like this:

```
    // Now create a message
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    //$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->setFrom('info@*****.com', 'first last');
    $mail->addAddress('info@*****.com');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
    $mail->Body = "Contact form submission:\n" . "Name: $sender_name\n";

    if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES) && $_FILES["userfile"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // First handle the upload
        // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
        // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            // Upload handled successfully
            // Attach the uploaded file
            //$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');

            $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            $ext = end((explode(".", $name)));
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'You Have Attachment.'.$ext);
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $msg .= "Message sent!";
    }
```

This way it will send the Email, and if there is a file attachment, it will be included.

Comment: I tried this, it does nothing without attachment, not sending at all, but when I attache the file it sends the mail without the attachment!

Comment: @Isabella I have edited the code, to include-  `&& $_FILES["userfile"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK` -which will check to see if there is no error, and the file uploaded successfully.

Comment: @Isabella if this worked, and solved the issue, please select it as the correct answer!

Comment: It worked in different way, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

It worked this way, now it is sending emails with/without attachment, also I altered many things such senders name and email to be variables and the body contents. Now I don't get any PHP errors and the form is working perfectly as I want, I hope this will help somebody, thank you all.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    // Create a message
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['sender_name']); //altered
    $mail->addAddress('info@***.com');
    $mail->Subject = 'Service Request';
    $mail->Body = "Sender: " .$_POST['sender_name'] ."\n" ."Phone: " .$_POST['phone']; //altered
    //Attach multiple files one by one
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
     $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
     $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
          $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        } 
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $msg .= "Message sent!";
    }
}
?>
```